Connecting shapes with a line in Microsoft Excel OfficeScript (TypeScript)
I am trying to connect two shapes with a line in Excel using OfficeScript, which is a superset of TypeScript, which is a superset of JavaScript.
I used Google Gemini to try and figure out the answer, and got this. It perfectly describes what I'm trying to do as pseudocode, but the worksheet object does not have the method insertConnector(), so it does not work.
// Get the two shapes you want to connect
const startShape = worksheet.getShapes().getByName("startShapeName");
const endShape = worksheet.getShapes().getByName("endShapeName");

// Create a connector object
const connector = worksheet.insertConnector(startShape, endShape);

// Choose a connector type (e.g., straight, elbow, etc.)
connector.setConnectorType(Excel.ConnectorType.Straight);

// Format the connector (optional)
connector.strokeLine({ color: "red" })

As an example, this is what I am trying to get as an end result:


The API is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel?view=excel-js-preview

Actually, it is this documentation you need for Office Script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/overview?view=office-scripts

As far as I can tell, connecting two shapes using a connector line isn't yet available. In my experience only the actions you can record are available, even when you write the script from scratch.


Using connectBeginShape and connectEndShape to connect line to desired shapes

Microsoft documentation:

ExcelScript.Line interface

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const FLOW_CHRT_DECI = ExcelScript.GeometricShapeType.flowChartDecision;
    let fcDecision1 = selectedSheet.addGeometricShape(FLOW_CHRT_DECI);
    fcDecision1.setLeft(40);
    fcDecision1.setTop(40);
    fcDecision1.setWidth(40);
    fcDecision1.setHeight(40);
    let fcDecision2 = selectedSheet.addGeometricShape(FLOW_CHRT_DECI);
    fcDecision2.setLeft(160);
    fcDecision2.setTop(40);
    fcDecision2.setWidth(40);
    fcDecision2.setHeight(40);
    // add a line
    let connLine = selectedSheet.addLine(0, 0, 10, 10, ExcelScript.ConnectorType.straight);
    // connect shapes
    connLine.getLine().connectBeginShape(fcDecision1, 3);
    connLine.getLine().connectEndShape(fcDecision2, 1);
}


